# Recognize new harddisk after hibernate wakeup

Tags: 10.10, hard-drive, hibernate, reboot

I hibernated my computer (suspend to disk) and added a new SATA disk. After resuming, my Ubuntu 10.10 does not recognize the new disk (while the BIOS did when starting up).

How can I get my machine to recognize the new hard drive *without rebooting*?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's supposed to work. A different approach would be to attach the disk after Ubuntu loaded (SATA *should* be hot-pluggable, but if it is, depends on your motherboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a [blog entry](http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2009/05/04/linux-sata-hot-plug-unplug/):

```
$ echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

I did that for all 4 channels, and voila - `/dev/sdb` is there now.